# My Responsive page works local but when i uploaded it on the school website, it stops being responsive

Tags: css, server, responsive

Hi I am new to HTML and CSS and I got the media query to work local but stops working when uploaded on the server. Any suggestions why? The meta name viewport is in the head and all I don't get why it breaks when uploaded. Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvYMk.png)
Here is the Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Genesis Manuel</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="subpages.css" type="text/css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <a href="index.html"> <h2>Genesis Manuel</h2></a>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="interests.html">Interests</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
            <div class="contain">
                <div id="leftside">
                    <main>
                        <h1> About Me</h1>      
                        <p> Born and raised in the Philippines, moved to Canada soon after.</p>
                        <p> A good cup of Coffee + dessert will always make me smile.</p>
                        <p> If you like cheesecake, we'll get along just fine.</p>
                        <p> Culinary will always be my first love.</p>
                        <hr>
                        <br>
                        <h1>Work&ndash;Wise</h1>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Problem&ndash;solver&mdash;A critical thinker, able to rise up to challenges.</li>
                                <li>Positivity&mdash; I never let anything bring me down in a high paced environment.</li>
                                <li>Accountable&mdash; I take full ownership of my work and see it through the end.</li>
                                <li>Kaizen&mdash; Always looking for ways to improve.</li>
                                <li>Initiative&mdash; I always try to be one step ahead.</li>
                            </ul>
                    </main>
                </div>
                <div id="rightside">
                    <img src="resumeimages/portrait.jpeg" alt="myself"/>
                </div>     
            </div>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@media (max-width: 428px) {
nav {
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: auto;
background-color: white;}
nav ul { list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 0%;
line-height: 3em;
;}
.contain {display: block;
justify-content: space-between;}
#leftside h1 {
color: black;
clear: left;}  
#leftside p {font-size: 1em;
text-align: right;
color: black;
line-height: 1.5em;
text-indent: 0%;
font-size: medium;
position: relative;
}
#leftside ul {
text-align: center;
color: black;
line-height: 1.5em;
text-indent: 0%;
font-size: medium;
}
}

@media (max-width: 820px) {
nav {
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: auto;
background-color: white;}
nav ul { list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 0%;
line-height: 3em;
;}
.contain {display: block;}
#leftside p {font-size: 1em;
text-align: center;
color: black;
line-height: 1.5em;
text-indent: 0%;
font-size: medium;
position: relative;
}
#leftside ul {
text-align: center;
color: red;
line-height: 1.5em;
text-indent: 0%;
font-size: medium;
}
}
```

I think I followed all the steps on the text, but I'm stumped on this one

Comment: Provide the Code inside your `<head>` tag please

Comment: Provide html in order to get help.

Comment: Its on the picture linked in the description, but i can copy and paste it here too if needed.

Comment: Yes, you need to copy and paste the codes here. We can't work on the image :)

Comment: <head>
  <title> Genesis Manuel</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="subpages.css" type="text/css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>

Comment: That ```<meta>``` tag alone can't do everything. You need to provide your html codes that can show the problem you are having to get help.

Comment: I just posted the html for one of my pages above. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: there's an error in the second selector of your media query, there is a semicolon too much at the end of the `nav ul`: `nav ul{ ;}`

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged your media queries because the 2nd one was overwriting the first one which it should not. And also corrected and organized your CSS. Now you can give it a go. I didn't make any change of the CSS to make change on the visual. You can specify how exactly you want it to look at a certain screen size and then it can be done.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title> Genesis Manuel</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      
      <style>        
        @media screen and (max-width: 820px){
          nav {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: auto;
            background-color:white;
          }

          nav ul { 
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-left: 0%;
            line-height: 3em;
          }
          
          .contain {
            display: block;
          }
        
          #leftside p {
            font-size: 1em;
            text-align:center;
            color: black;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            text-indent: 0%;
            font-size:medium;
            position: relative;
          }

          #leftside ul {
            text-align: center;
            color: red;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            text-indent: 0%;
            font-size:medium;
          }
        }
        
        @media screen and (max-width: 428px) {
          nav {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: auto;
            background-color:white;
          }
          
          nav ul { 
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-left: 0%;
            line-height: 3em;
          }
        
          .contain {
            display: block;
            justify-content: space-between;
          }
          
          #leftside h1 {
            color:black;
            clear: left;
          }  
          
          #leftside p {
            font-size: 1em;
            text-align:right;
            color: black;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            text-indent: 0%;
            font-size:medium;
            position: relative;
          }

          #leftside ul {
            text-align: center;
            color: black;
            line-height: 1.5em;
            text-indent: 0%;
            font-size:medium;
          }
        }
      </style>       

    </head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <header>
          <a href="index.html"> <h2>Genesis Manuel</h2></a>
      </header>
      <nav>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
              <li><a href="interests.html">Interests</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="contain">
          <div id="leftside">
              <main>
                  <h1> About Me</h1>      
                  <p> Born and raised in the Philippines, moved to Canada soon after.</p>
                  <p> A good cup of Coffee + dessert will always make me smile.</p>
                  <p> If you like cheesecake, we'll get along just fine.</p>
                  <p> Culinary will always be my first love.</p>
                  <hr>
                  <br>
                  <h1>Work&ndash;Wise</h1>
                      <ul>
                          <li>Problem&ndash;solver&mdash;A critical thinker, able to rise up to challenges.</li>
                          <li>Positivity&mdash; I never let anything bring me down in a high paced environment.</li>
                          <li>Accountable&mdash; I take full ownership of my work and see it through the end.</li>
                          <li>Kaizen&mdash; Always looking for ways to improve.</li>
                          <li>Initiative&mdash; I always try to be one step ahead.</li>
                      </ul>
              </main>
          </div>
          <div id="rightside">
              <img src="resumeimages/portrait.jpeg" alt="myself"/>
          </div>     
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```